# Spring WS - step by step in STS (from WSDL)

Tags: java, web-services, spring, spring-ws

I am trying to create a new Spring webservice project in Spring Tool Suite (STS). I checked this link
http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/tutorial.html
But this doesn't tell the steps very clearly.

Can anyone please share links to some useful resources that show step-by-step how to create a Spring WS project?

Comment: what is not clear in tutorial?

Comment: @Jigar Parekh - project structure - unclear, file names unclear too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this small article on how to create a simple web service using Spring . This is in line with Spring tutorial. Perhaps this will help.

http://codereq.com/spring-web-service-part-1/

Thanks,
Tejas.

Comment: error 404. Site not found.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe these links will be helpful:

[Step by step Spring-WS](http://springtips.blogspot.com/2007/07/step-by-step-spring-ws.html)
[Spring Web Services](http://www.javabeat.net/2010/06/introduction-to-spring-web-services/)
[Simple Spring Web Services](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-spring-web-services.html)
[Basic Spring Web Service Tutorial From Contract to Security](http://jeromebulanadi.wordpress.com/2010/02/25/basic-spring-web-service-tutorial-from-contract-to-security)

Answer (score 3):

Try this one. You can see in the screen-shot that the IDE has the famous Spring logo: http://briansjavablog.blogspot.com/2013/01/spring-web-services-tutorial.html

Comment: Here's another which is a little more complete since it fills in a missing part about  using mvn eclipse:eclipse to get the STS project file created so that the projects can be imported and worked with in STS: http://ankeetmaini.wordpress.com/2011/10/24/spring-web-services-2-made-easy/ Moreover, this one does not try to be fancy but is the simplest by far. I recommend this one 1st to get your feet wet then going to the site above for a detailed explanation of what's going on.