# Spring 3.1 Web services working example

Tags: spring-ws, spring-tool-suite

Please suggest me with some useful links that have step by step spring web services sample examples implementation. Do I need to install some plugin in Spring Tool Suite.

Comment: Do you mean REST services in Spring 3.1 (MVC based) or Spring-WS SOAP services? These are two different things.

Comment: This link has few examples which might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267863/spring-ws-step-by-step-in-sts-from-wsdl

Answer (score 1):

As said by @evandongen, Spring 3.1 features REST web services. SOAP web services can be implemented with Spring-WS, which currently is in version 2.1.3. [The Spring-WS manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/tutorial.html) has a tutorial which shows you step-by-step how to implement a SOAP web service.